# Divs not lining up properly

Tags: html, css

I'm making a website for my friend. He has a 3dprinter and makes prints for people. Right now I have a landing page and 3 divs with information, prices and a form for people to submit prints. I want these divs to display next to eachother with the tops all being right next to eachother [image: Like this]

Right now they are positioned differently. Check this snippet

```css
/* Color Scheme: https://coolors.co/333333-e4fde1-c9cebd-648381-f0eff4 */

* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

html, body{
 background: #E4FDE1;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}

#background {
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
 filter: blur(40px);
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 background-image: url('https://jorik.tk/3dprint/img/3d-printing-2.jpg');
  background-position: center;
  border-bottom: solid 5px #333333;
}

#blur {
 color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
 color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}

#content {
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0 auto;
 display: table;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 30%;
}

#content h1 {
 width: 100%;
 text-align: center;
  visibility: visible;
  font-family: Roboto Slab;
  font-size: 500%;
  color: #333333;
  filter: none;
}

#title-wrap {
 width: 40%;
 display: table-cell;
 text-align: center;
 background-color: #c9cebd;
 opacity: 0.6;
}

#lm-button {
 display: table;
 position: absolute;
 top: 60%;
 text-align: center;
 width: 100%;
 height: 6%;
 background: #648381;
 opacity: 0.6;
 transition: opacity 0.6s;
}

#lm-button:hover {
 opacity: 1;
}

#lm-button p {
 font-family: Ubuntu, sans-serif;
 font-size: 130%;
 line-height: 250%;
 opacity: 1;
 
}

#info {
 margin: auto;
 border-top: solid 10px #333333;
 z-index: 5;
}

#contact {
 margin: auto;
}

@media (max-width: 685px) {
 #content h1 {
  font-size: 300%;
 }
}

#text {
 text-align: center; 
}

#uitleg {
 text-align: center;
 font-family: 'Varela Round', sans-serif;
}

.inline {
 display: block;
}

#prijzen {
 text-align: center;
}

h3 {
 text-align: center;
 font-family: Ubuntu, sans-serif;
}

.inlines {
 display: inline-block;
 margin: auto;
 width: 300px;
 background: #648381;
 height: 400px;
 padding: 30px;
}

#inlinescontainer {
 margin: 20px auto;
 max-width: 1200px;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather|Roboto+Slab|Ubuntu" rel="stylesheet">
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu" rel="stylesheet">
      <link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
      <link rel="shortcut icon" href=""/>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
      <title>3D Printen</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="background"></div>
      <div id="content">
         <div id="title-wrap">
            <h1>3D Printen in stijl.</h1>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div onclick="scrollToInfo()" id="lm-button">
         <p id="lm-button-text">Meer info</p>
      </div>
      <div id="info">
      </div>
      <div id="inlinescontainer">
         <div class="inlines">
            <p id="uitleg">Zoek op <a href="https://yeggi.com" target="_blank">yeggi.com</a> iets wat je wilt dat ik voor je print,
               stuur de link hieronder samen met je email en welke kleur je wilt naar mij toe.
               Je ontvangt dan een mail met de afmetingen van de print. Je kan de print nog annuleren door me terug te mailen. 
               Als het klaar is krijg je je print de volgende dag. (Je moet hiervoor wel op het Greijdanus zitten) Hieronder zie je de tarieven.
               De beschikbare kleuren zijn: Blauw, zwart en goud.<br><br><i>(Max 10 meter per print toegestaan)</i>
            </p>
         </div>
         <div class="inlines">
            <h3>Tarieven</h3>
            <p id="prijzen">
               1 meter: €0,10<br>
               2 meter: €0,30<br>
               3 meter: €0,40<br>
               4 meter: €0,50<br>
               5 meter: €0,70<br>
               6 meter: €0,80<br>
               7 meter: €0,90<br>
               8 meter: €1,10<br>
               9 meter: €1,20<br>
               10 meter: €1,30<br>
            </p>
         </div>
         <div class="inlines">
            <div id="contact">
               <form id="contact-form" name="form" method="POST" action="">
                  <input type="text" placeholder="email" name="email" id="email" class="inline">
                  <textarea placeholder="bericht" name="message" id="bericht" cols="40" rows="5" class="inline"></textarea>
                  <?php echo '<input type="hidden" value="'. $idnull . '" name="id">' ?>
                  <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Stuur!" class="inline">
               </form>
               <p id="text"><?php if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) and $email != "") {echo "Voer A.U.B. een geldig e-mail adres in";} ?></p>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

*I know this code has different issues, but that's not the focus of this question*

Does anyone know how I could achieve the effect in the picture above? If so. Please give an answer. Thank you in advance!

Comment: can you please provide same on jsfiddle

Comment: If you want to view this on fullscreen. You could go to https://jorik.tk/3dprint . Anyways https://jsfiddle.net/w7rvxo0s/ there you go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a minor change in your css add     `vertical-align: middle;` to *.inlines*

```
.inlines {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: auto;
    width: 300px;
    background: #648381;
    height: 400px;
    padding: 30px;
    vertical-align: middle; /*Added*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
/* Color Scheme: https://coolors.co/333333-e4fde1-c9cebd-648381-f0eff4 */
/*Add 'vertical-align: top;' to .inlines class in your css*/

* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

html, body{
 background: #E4FDE1;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}

#background {
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
 filter: blur(40px);
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 background-image: url('https://jorik.tk/3dprint/img/3d-printing-2.jpg');
  background-position: center;
  border-bottom: solid 5px #333333;
}

#blur {
 color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
 color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}

#content {
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0 auto;
 display: table;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 30%;
}

#content h1 {
 width: 100%;
 text-align: center;
  visibility: visible;
  font-family: Roboto Slab;
  font-size: 500%;
  color: #333333;
  filter: none;
}

#title-wrap {
 width: 40%;
 display: table-cell;
 text-align: center;
 background-color: #c9cebd;
 opacity: 0.6;
}

#lm-button {
 display: table;
 position: absolute;
 top: 60%;
 text-align: center;
 width: 100%;
 height: 6%;
 background: #648381;
 opacity: 0.6;
 transition: opacity 0.6s;
}

#lm-button:hover {
 opacity: 1;
}

#lm-button p {
 font-family: Ubuntu, sans-serif;
 font-size: 130%;
 line-height: 250%;
 opacity: 1;
 
}

#info {
 margin: auto;
 border-top: solid 10px #333333;
 z-index: 5;
}

#contact {
 margin: auto;
}

@media (max-width: 685px) {
 #content h1 {
  font-size: 300%;
 }
}

#text {
 text-align: center; 
}

#uitleg {
 text-align: center;
 font-family: 'Varela Round', sans-serif;
}

.inline {
 display: block;
}

#prijzen {
 text-align: center;
}

h3 {
 text-align: center;
 font-family: Ubuntu, sans-serif;
}

.inlines {
 display: inline-block;
 margin: auto;
 width: 300px;
 background: #648381;
 height: 400px;
 padding: 30px;
  vertical-align: top;
}

#inlinescontainer {
 margin: 20px auto;
 max-width: 1200px;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather|Roboto+Slab|Ubuntu" rel="stylesheet">
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu" rel="stylesheet">
      <link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
      <link rel="shortcut icon" href=""/>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
      <title>3D Printen</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="background"></div>
      <div id="content">
         <div id="title-wrap">
            <h1>3D Printen in stijl.</h1>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div onclick="scrollToInfo()" id="lm-button">
         <p id="lm-button-text">Meer info</p>
      </div>
      <div id="info">
      </div>
      <div id="inlinescontainer">
         <div class="inlines">
            <p id="uitleg">Zoek op <a href="https://yeggi.com" target="_blank">yeggi.com</a> iets wat je wilt dat ik voor je print,
               stuur de link hieronder samen met je email en welke kleur je wilt naar mij toe.
               Je ontvangt dan een mail met de afmetingen van de print. Je kan de print nog annuleren door me terug te mailen. 
               Als het klaar is krijg je je print de volgende dag. (Je moet hiervoor wel op het Greijdanus zitten) Hieronder zie je de tarieven.
               De beschikbare kleuren zijn: Blauw, zwart en goud.<br><br><i>(Max 10 meter per print toegestaan)</i>
            </p>
         </div>
         <div class="inlines">
            <h3>Tarieven</h3>
            <p id="prijzen">
               1 meter: €0,10<br>
               2 meter: €0,30<br>
               3 meter: €0,40<br>
               4 meter: €0,50<br>
               5 meter: €0,70<br>
               6 meter: €0,80<br>
               7 meter: €0,90<br>
               8 meter: €1,10<br>
               9 meter: €1,20<br>
               10 meter: €1,30<br>
            </p>
         </div>
         <div class="inlines">
            <div id="contact">
               <form id="contact-form" name="form" method="POST" action="">
                  <input type="text" placeholder="email" name="email" id="email" class="inline">
                  <textarea placeholder="bericht" name="message" id="bericht" cols="40" rows="5" class="inline"></textarea>
                  <?php echo '<input type="hidden" value="'. $idnull . '" name="id">' ?>
                  <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Stuur!" class="inline">
               </form>
               <p id="text"><?php if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) and $email != "") {echo "Voer A.U.B. een geldig e-mail adres in";} ?></p>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve like this:

html:

```
<div class="full-container">
    <div class="col-third inline-block">content</div>
    <div class="col-third inline-block">content</div>
    <div class="col-third inline-block">content</div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.full-container {width: 100%}
.col-third      {margin: 0 4px; width: 32%}
.inline-block   {display: inline-block}
```

you may need to adjust margin based on what's wanted (this is example code - not a copy and paste answer)

Answer (score 0):

When you use `display: inline-block;` then `vertical-align: top;` is recommended or almost mandatory, try it:

```
.inlines {
display: inline-block;
margin: auto;
width: 300px;
background: #648381;
height: 400px;
padding: 30px;
vertical-align: top; // Key line
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `.inlines` CSS code with this one:

```
float: left;
width: 300px;
background: #648381;
height: 400px;
padding: 30px;
margin: 20px 20px 50px;
```

You should use `float:left` instead `display:inline-block`. Hope this helps.

Comment: no you shouldn't - `float` should be hardly ever used